# Installing Symfony debug bar not working in 6.5.7.3

Tags: shopware6

I have installed (locally, Mamp) of the latest Shopware (6.5.7.3). But if I try to install the Symfony debug tools with:

`composer require shopware/dev-tools`

I get this error:

````
  Problem 1
    - symfony/flex is locked to version v2.4.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/flex v2.4.2 requires composer-plugin-api ^2.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/framework-bundle v6.3.9 requires composer-runtime-api >=2.1 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - shopware/storefront v6.5.7.3 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~6.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v6.3.9].
    - shopware/storefront is locked to version v6.5.7.3 and an update of this package was not requested.

You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.```

It used to work on previous versions (6.5.7.0 ?). And, if I update Shopware from, for example 6.5.7.0 to 6.5.7.3, it still works. But can not install in a fresh 6.5.7.3.

Anyone knows how to fix this?
````